# Implementing the Apache Spark tutorial with FP-growth, No results on freqItemsets

Tags: scala, apache-spark, data-mining

This is my first question here and I hope I am doing this correctly.

So, I was trying to get into Apache Spark and its FP-growth algorithm. Therefore i tried to apply the FP-growth tutorial to the bank tutorial that comes with Spark.

I am really new to all this data-mapping stuff und scala, so this question might seem very basic for you guys, but i appreciate your help!

```
case class Bank(age:Integer, job: String, marital: String, education: 
                String, balance: Integer)

val bank = bankTest.map(s=>s.split(";")).filter(s=>s(0)!= "\"age\"").map(
 s=>Bank(s(0).toInt,
         s(1).replaceAll("\"", ""),
         s(2).replaceAll("\"", ""),
         s(3).replaceAll("\"", ""),
         s(5).replaceAll("\"", "").toInt

  )
)

val transactions: RDD[Array[Object]] = bank.map(x => Array(x))

val fpg = new FPGrowth()
  .setMinSupport(0.1)
  .setNumPartitions(10)
val model = fpg.run(transactions)

model.freqItemsets.collect().foreach { itemset =>
  println(itemset.items.mkString("[", ",", "]") + ", " + itemset.freq)
}
```

This is what I coded and I think the problem is the mapping of my bank element into the transactions variable. The code runs properly, but there are no results. I guess this happens because the FP-growth algorithm compares the different objects of the type bank with each other, which are contained in the transaction variable. Of course there is no whole object with a support of 20%.

So the question is: How can I make the FP-growth check for the COLUMNS in my data and not for the whole object?

For example: The support for "job = manager" should be around 20%, so it should appear as frequent, which it does not in my results.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: The Problem here seems to be as i thought. When I use 

    transactions = bankTest.map(s => s.split(";"))

as my RDD, I get the error that the values must be unique. In this splitted String they are not. Therefore i put them in my object first.

Okay, I think I am starting to understand. Is there any way, I can split my object into its different parts?

Answer (score 0):

An easy solution would be to create a toList method that simply returns a list with all the member of your bank:

```
case class Bank(age:Integer, job: String, marital: String, education: String, balance: Integer)
{
    def toList():List[String]=
    {
        List(""+age, job, marital, education, ""+balance);
    }
}
```

Note that I used a List of String as FP-growth works with "classified items". It means that if you input integers or floats as salary or age, it will treat every single salary as unique if they differ by a cent (the same for age):

```
val bank1 = Bank(35, "engineer", "engaged", "college", 100000)
val bank2 = Bank(35, "engineer", "engaged", "college", 100001)
```

Although the salary of `bank1` and `bank2` is very close, FP-growth will consider this two items as different. Thus you will have trouble classifying salaries as they have a high divergence.

I would recommend to define an `enum` for each *age class* and *salary class* such as `AGE_BETWEEN_0_18`, `AGE_BETWEEN_18_25` ...

That way you will shrink the histogram and let FP-growth work perfectly.

P.S.: I am not sure the object should be called `Bank`, I would rather name it `BankCustomer`